# Wondering why minifying my Javascript causes event bindings to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I minified my Javascript using one of the websites that does it for you. No problems with any functions or for the most part, any of my bindings either. One binding however:

```
$("#calIcon").on('click', function (e) {
    $('#reservationtime').data('daterangepicker').show(e);
});
```

becomes fully non-functional after minifying the Javascript. It is strange because I can quite literally Control+Z the JS file, save it, refresh the page, and the binding is fine. Control +Y, save, it stops working again.

Is this a known issue or is there something I should be doing differently when minifying my Javascript?

Edit: The minifier output the code as

```
$("#calIcon").on("click", function (e) { $("#reservationtime").data("daterangepicker").show(e) }),
```

Also, I was testing ending the binding with ',' and ';' - netiher worked, but the minifier was what originally put a comma on the end where there was neither a comma nor a semicolon.

Edit 2:

The line immediately before and after the function in question:

```
$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on("click", function () { $(".dropdown dd ul").hide() }), $("#calIcon").on("click", function (e) { $("#reservationtime").data("daterangepicker").show(e) }), $(document).bind("click", function (e) { var t = $(e.target); t.parents().hasClass("dropdown") || $(".dropdown dd ul").hide() }),
```

Comment: It would seem like the minification site you were using isn't doing a great job. I might recommend using a different service, or Uglify/YUI/Closure Compiler if you want something tried and tested.

Comment: just for interest, can you show use the minified output of that function?

Comment: Sure, I added the code of how it was output. Is this a good resource for Uglify? http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/

Comment: It may be a good idea to show all the javascript, and state which site you used to minify it. The code you think is the problem may not be the problem.

Comment: Are you minifying to a single file? Maybe you have a dependency that's not loaded yet, or it's included too early (before docReady or in the head)?

Comment: I use this http://refresh-sf.com

Comment: @Popnoodles the file is quite large and basically everything but that line is sort of irrelevant.

Comment: Is it follow by another function?

Comment: @BradChristie Yes I'm minifying to a single file, all of the dependencies are being loaded in the same order as when the file isn't minified and there are no errors being thrown.

Comment: Any console errors after minifying? Because if binding failed due to syntax error, then there must be some error on the console.

Comment: @afrin216 That's what I'm not understanding. It just stops working completely, period. There are no errors, no functionality, nothing. It's like it completely disregards that lines existence after minifying.

Comment: @Popnoodles, it is valid JS, it hides the dropdown when a click on the document occurs that is not witin the dropdown

Comment: I'd say this is not worth debugging. It might be as @MaximillianLaumeister said, the website's issue. Unless your requirement is that you _must_ use that specific website, I'd say better spend your time finding an alternate website that does a better job.

Comment: I've now used Uglify and the website recommended by @EasyBB (which I believe is using Uglify anyway). These produced the same results unfortunately. Unless Uglify is minifying incorrectly, which I doubt, this is something very specific causing the issue.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors, is there a doc ready wrapper, are there any proceeding code?

Comment: @afrin216 It probably isn't worth debugging as I can simply put that piece of JS on the page, but it would be interesting/nice to know what's causing this very specific issue, that doesn't throw errors and that seems to happen irrespective of what tool is used to minify.

Comment: Ok. Since both websites are producing same error, I've some basic questions for you - Is your modified js file missing jquery library file as in did you forget to include it after minification? Is part of the js file working, and only this function loses its functionality?

Comment: @afrin216 jQuery is the first thing I load in, then bootstrap, then some other crap, then my JS. Again, the console does not throw errors (on Chrome or in IE) with anything using a '$' selector (or actually any errors at all), so jQuery is loading fine. Yes, all 1200 lines of my JS work correctly after minifying, except that 1 binding.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see where it is failing? The problem could be that your `click` handler is not getting called or any of the three functions it calls (`$`, `data`, and `show`) could be failing.

Comment: Can you replace the `,` at the end with a `;`? The only other difference I see is the use of double quotes instead of single quotes...

Comment: @JackA. Again it is hard to know since the console claims there are no issues.

Comment: @RonBeyer I had actually tried that without any luck, I also tried changing the 'e' variable it uses to something different, as 'e' was being used a lot elsewhere. That didn't help either.

Comment: Most browsers provide a JavaScript debugger in addition to a console. The debugger is going to be your best friend here.